# What are the best dimensions for homepage banners for desktop and mobile?

Tags: design, banner-slider

Got some formatting issues with banners not viewing properly in mobile in landscape rotation. Height is ok but the width is wrong.

Any advice on sizing images for banners and best dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

Magento uses the file called `view.xml` which is maintained at the theme level of the application.

So for example, if you are using the default theme `luma` you should find the `view.xml` under `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml`

In this file, you would see `<images/>` node inside the `<media>` node.

```
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="bundled_product_customization_page" type="thumbnail">
                <width>140</width>
                <height>140</height>
            </image>
            <image id="cart_cross_sell_products" type="thumbnail">
                <width>200</width>
                <height>248</height>
            </image>
            <image id="cart_page_product_thumbnail" type="small_image">
                <width>165</width>
                <height>165</height>
            </image>
            ........
        </images>
    </media>
    ......
</view>
```

The dimension of the images is maintained here under the `<image/>` node.

The `id` attribute value of the `<image/>` node is referenced in the codebase.

For example:

```
<image id="related_products_list" type="small_image">
    <width>152</width>
    <height>190</height>
</image>
```